# Java I/O FileStream issue

Tags: java, file-io, java-8

I have an input file stream method that will load a file, I just can't figure out how to then use the file in another method. The file has one UTF string and two integers. How can I now use each of these different ints or strings in a main method? Lets say I want print the three different variables to the console, how would I go about doing that? Here's a few things I've tried with the method:

```
public static  dataStreams() throws IOException { 
    int i = 0;
    char c;
    try (DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(
            new FileInputStream("input.dat"));
    ) {

        while((i=input.read())!=-1){
             // converts integer to character
            c=(char)i;
        }

        return c;
        return i;
    /*  
        String stringUTF = input.readUTF();
        int firstInt = input.readInt();
        int secondInt = input.readInt();
        */


    }


}
```

Comment: maybe you can create an object with those properties, one String and 2 ints

Comment: After doing so, I received an error "Unhanded exception type IOException" in the other method after declaring the dataStreams, what could be the problem? Thanks

Comment: Bumping it up, because its a valid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe one container for those properties, like this:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
        DataContainer dContainer = null;
    try {
        dContainer = dataStreams();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //do some logging with properties
    System.out.println(dContainer.getFirst());
    System.out.println(dContainer.getSecond());
    System.out.println(dContainer.getUtf());
    }

    public static DataContainer dataStreams() throws IOException { 
        int i = 0;
        char c;
        try (DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(
                new FileInputStream("input.dat"));
        ) {

            while((i=input.read())!=-1){
                 // converts integer to character
                c=(char)i;
            }



            String stringUTF = input.readUTF();
            int firstInt = input.readInt();
            int secondInt = input.readInt();

            DataContainer dContainer = new DataContainer(stringUTF, firstInt, secondInt);
            return dContainer;
        }


    }

    static class DataContainer {
        String utf;
        int first;
        int second;
        DataContainer(String utf, int first, int second) {
            this.utf = utf;
            this.first = first;
            this.second = second;
        }
        public String getUtf() {
            return utf;
        }
        public int getFirst() {
            return first;
        }
        public int getSecond() {
            return second;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I wrote something similar using objects but  when I declare the variable for dataStrems in the other  method I get an error "Unhanded exception  type IOException". This is where I'm stuck at now.

Comment: sure, you need to use a try-catch because in your dataStreams method you are throwing that exception

Comment: I have added a try-catch